# Finding an unknown multiplying the determinant of a matrix A when given a modified matrix A

Tags: matrices, determinant

I need to solve the following problem:

$\det\begin{bmatrix} 7a_1 & 7a_2 & 7a_3\\4b_1+8c_1  & 4b_2+8c_2   & 4b_3+8c_3 \\ 6c_1 & 6c_2 & 6c_3\end{bmatrix}=k\det \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}$

I did the following:
$\det\begin{bmatrix} 7a_1 & 7a_2 & 7a_3\\4b_1+8c_1  & 4b_2+8c_2   & 4b_3+8c_3 \\ 6c_1 & 6c_2 & 6c_3\end{bmatrix}=7\cdot 6\cdot \det\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\4b_1+8c_1  & 4b_2+8c_2   & 4b_3+8c_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}$

I then recalled that if matrix A is obtained from matrix B by adding a multiple of one row to another, then $\det A=\det B$.  So, 
$\det\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\4b_1+8c_1  & 4b_2+8c_2   & 4b_3+8c_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix} = \det\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\4b_1  & 4b_2   & 4b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix} = 4\cdot \det \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}$

This makes $k=6\cdot 7\cdot 4=168$.  Is my logic correct here?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your logic and step by step simplification to get $$\det\begin{bmatrix} 7a_1 & 7a_2 & 7a_3\\4b_1+8c_1  & 4b_2+8c_2   & 4b_3+8c_3 \\ 6c_1 & 6c_2 & 6c_3\end{bmatrix}=168\det \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{bmatrix}$$

is correct.

Comment: It is not a good practice to simply post that the proof is correct.

Comment: @Jose Isn't that what the OP asked for?

Comment: It is. But in MSE it is considered bad practice to answer a proof-verification question simply saying that the proof is correct.

Comment: Thanks,  What does MSE stand for?

Comment: Math StackExchange

Comment: I should have guessed, thanks.

Comment: I actually think that posting that a proof is correct should be fine, since that's what was asked. On the other hand, the answerer in such cases doesn't really do a lot of work or provide much insight, and I tend to make such answers "Community Wiki" so that I don't get points for them, but the questions CAN be 'closed out'. (I'm not saying that's what @MohammadRiazi-Kermani should have done -- it's just a possible course of action that has multiple benefits.)